# Converting standard LAMP installation to Docker?

Tags: docker, lamp, php-7

I'm trying to learn Docker and convert the LAMP stack installation below that I have been using to Docker:

```
# Install Apache

    $ sudo apt-get install apache2

# Install PHP  (PHP7)

    $ sudo apt-get update 
    $ sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql php7.0-curl php7.0-json php7.0-cgi  php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7

# Install PHP Curl

    sudo apt-get install php-curl

# Install MySQL

    $ sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
    $ sudo systemctl status mysql

# Manage MySQL Databases (Optional)

    $ sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin

Open terminal, and type:

    $ sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Add the following line at the end:

    include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf

Save and Exit. Restart apache service:

    $ sudo systemctl restart apache2

# Edit config & change html directory

The document root was set to /var/www/html. It was configured in the following file:

    /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

So just do:

    $sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

and change the following line to what you want:

    DocumentRoot /var/www

Also:

    $ sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Find:

    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

Change `/var/www/html` to your preferred directory: `/var/www/`

Restart:

    $ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

# Enabling mod_rewrite

    $ sudo a2enmod rewrite
    $ service apache2 restart
```

My DockerFile (I follow this Docker [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxconfig/lamp/~/dockerfile/)):

```
FROM linuxconfig/apache:latest

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

# Main package installation
RUN apt-get update

# Install PHP 7
RUN apt-get -y install php7.0-mysql php7.0-curl php7.0-json php7.0-cgi  php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7

# Install PHP Curl

RUN apt-get -y install php-curl

# Install MySQLs
RUN apt-get -y install supervisor mysql-server mysql-client

# Configure MySQL
RUN sed -i 's/bind-address/#bind-address/' /etc/mysql/my.cnf

# Install phpmyadmin
RUN apt-get -y install phpmyadmin

# Include supervisor configuration
ADD supervisor-lamp.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/
ADD supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/

# Include PHP Info page
ADD index.php /var/www/html/index.php

# Create new MySQL admin user
RUN service mysql start; mysql -u root -e "CREATE USER 'admin'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';";mysql -u root -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;";

# Allow ports
EXPOSE 80 3306

# Start supervisor
CMD ["supervisord"]
```

I run it on my terminal:

```
$ docker build -t docker-lamp .
```

But I get this error:

```
E: Unable to locate package php7.0-mysql
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0-mysql'
E: Unable to locate package php7.0-curl
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0-curl'
E: Unable to locate package php7.0-json
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0-json'
E: Unable to locate package php7.0-cgi
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0-cgi'
E: Unable to locate package php7.0
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0'
E: Unable to locate package libapache2-mod-php7
```

Why do I have that error? What have I done wrong?

Also, in my standard LAMP installation, I must configure phpMyadmin:

```
Open terminal, and type:

    $ sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Add the following line at the end:

    include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf

Save and Exit. Restart apache service:

    $ sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

How can I do that in Docker?

The full output on my terminal:

```
$ docker build -t docker-lamp .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.56 kB
Step 1 : FROM linuxconfig/apache:latest
latest: Pulling from linuxconfig/apache
75a822cd7888: Pull complete 
7265e4579453: Pull complete 
7a28f7c3739d: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:dcbb38ea5028d09dd5aeb4b5cd343285d44edc616ec66cf7e5ba4dcee0a5bb8c
Status: Downloaded newer image for linuxconfig/apache:latest
 ---> 89a6a2f193ec
Step 2 : ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
 ---> Running in 144fad888f01
 ---> 01681a524cef
Removing intermediate container 144fad888f01
Step 3 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Running in eba267dccc10
Get:1 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease [63.1 kB]
Ign http://deb.debian.org jessie InRelease
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease [145 kB]
Hit http://deb.debian.org jessie Release.gpg
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages [17.6 kB]
Hit http://deb.debian.org jessie Release
Get:4 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages [430 kB]
Get:5 http://deb.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages [9064 kB]
Fetched 9719 kB in 2min 46s (58.4 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
 ---> 9fd9f0de570d
Removing intermediate container eba267dccc10
Step 4 : RUN apt-get -y install php7.0-mysql php7.0-curl php7.0-json php7.0-cgi  php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7
 ---> Running in dcc079249142
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package php7.0-mysql
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0-mysql'
E: Unable to locate package php7.0-curl
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0-curl'
E: Unable to locate package php7.0-json
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0-json'
E: Unable to locate package php7.0-cgi
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0-cgi'
E: Unable to locate package php7.0
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0'
E: Unable to locate package libapache2-mod-php7
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get -y install php7.0-mysql php7.0-curl php7.0-json php7.0-cgi  php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Any ideas?

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 by the way.